# Pagination in ngx datatable using abp framework

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination, pager, abp

How can I show pagination footer in ngx datatable in abp framework for angular?

I am using ListService with PagedResultDto, should I implement pagination externally?

```
          <ngx-datatable [scrollbarH]="false" (activate)="onActivate($event)"  [rows]="auditImportsByCreatorId.items" [count]="auditImportsByCreatorId.totalCount" default>
            <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Proceed Date' | abpLocalization" prop="importDate">
              <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row.importDate | date}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::File Name' | abpLocalization" prop="displayFileName">
              <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row.displayFileName}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Number of Claims' | abpLocalization" prop="recordCount">
              <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row.recordCount}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Contact/Requestor' | abpLocalization" prop="contactName">
              <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row.contactName}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Return Status' | abpLocalization" prop="returnStatus">
              <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ getStautsValue(row.returnStatus)}}
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
          </ngx-datatable>
```

Answer (score 1):

ABP framework ngx-datatable pagination will appear when total number of records is greater than 10.

The default value of ListService's maxResultCount is 10.

You can change the value of maxResultCount in component as shown below:

```
    constructor(public readonly list: ListService) {
        this.list.maxResultCount = 2;
    }
```

Now you can see the pagination as soon as number of records greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

**You can for pagination in abp ngx angular:**

1. first : book.component.html : [NGX Sample](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/3.0/Tutorials/Part-3?UI=NG&DB=EF)

   ```
      <ngx-datatable [rows]="book.items" [count]="book.totalCount"   [list]="list"  (page)="onPage($event)"default></ngx-datatable>
   ```
2. book.component.ts : [ABP sample](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/3.0/Tutorials/Part-3?UI=NG&DB=EF)

   ```
     constructor(public readonly list: ListService){
              getBooks = {} as GetBooksInputDto;
          }
   ```

   The default value of ListService maxResultCount is 10.

   ```
   ngOnInit(): void {                           
       this.list.maxResultCount=10;
       this.getList(this.getBooks);
     }
   ```

   event contain : {"count": 3,"pageSize": 2,"limit": 2,"offset":}

   ```
   onPage(event) {

    console.log(event)
    this.getPages.skipCount = event.offset;

    }
   ```

   ```
   getBooks = {} as GetBooksInputDto;
   ```

   ```
   getList(queryFilter: GetBooksInputDto) {
       this.getBooks.maxResultCount = this.list.maxResultCount;
       const bookStreamCreator = 
             (query)=>this.bookService.getList(queryFilter, query);
            this.list.hookToQuery(bookStreamCreator).subscribe((response) =>   
             {
              this.book = response;
            });
        }
   ```